# Select option in PHP with MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<html>
<head>
<title>The Reservation</title><link rel='stylesheet' href='designstudent.css'>
</head>
<body>

<?php

    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '')
            or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db('shuttle_service_system') 
    or die(mysql_error());

 $info =mysql_query("
    SELECT  DISTINC Location_From AS 'LocationFrom'
    FROM trip
");
    echo "<select class = 'LocationFrom' select size='1'>";
    while($check = mysql_fetch_array($info))
{
    echo "<option>" . $check['trip.Location_From'] . "</option>";
}
echo"</select>";

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Hi guys I am making a shuttle reservation system with a drop down menu that is coming from a MySQL, I cannot make the data on the MySQL appear in the drop down menu.

Comment: Change `$check['trip.Location_From']` to `$check['LocationFrom']`

Comment: what's the error you are getting? try `echo "<option>" . $check['LocationFrom'] . "</option>";` instead
the table name is not a neccesity and you put an alias to Location_From => LocationFrom

Comment: Tried that, nothing happened.

Comment: I don't get any errors but the drop down menu is empty when I run it.

Comment: Probably because of the syntax error in your SQL: `DISTINC` should be `DISTINCT`.  And your `<select>` tag has an extra "select" that shouldn't be there.

Comment: You won't get any errors, because you're not checking for errors. You need to check the return value from `mysql_query`, and look in `mysql_error()` to see what the issue is. You've got a typo in `SELECT DISTINC ` (it's missing a T at the end of DISTINCT), and the array you're retrieving doesn't have an index of `trip.Location_From`

Comment: Thank you guys! Sorry for such a rookie mistake.

Answer (score 0):

**Check your error logs.**

You should be getting a MySQL exception because the keyword `DISTINCT` is misspelled.

Answer (score 0):

Use **group by Location_From** and NOT **distinct** in mysql